# Testing files to only include specific folder for nx run-many

Tags: angular, jestjs, nxjs

In package.json there is the following task:

```
{
  "test": "nx run-many --target=test --code-coverage --projects=myproject, anotherproject --parallel --maxParallel"
}
```

Now for just the Angular project 'myproject' I would like to **run only in a specific folder**.

That would be able with the command line argument: `--test-path-pattern=\".*specific-folder($|.*.[spec.ts])\"`.

However, since I am running tasks in parallel setting such a command line argument would apply to all the projects rather than just one.

Is it possible to configure this in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

Via [Jest config](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration) it's possible to target files/folders.

**jest.config.ts**

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  testMatch: ['**/specific-folder/**/*.spec.ts'],
}
```

Either via [testMatch](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring) or [testRegex](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testregex-string--arraystring).

Now you can just run the project's tests and it will only target files in that folder.